# swift Stack insertSubview & auto refresh layout problem

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, addsubview

I would like to click and add subview at: index 3 position. But the constraint not update automatically. how can i refresh the layout when adding subview to uistack?

Thank you for your help very much

```
@objc func showMoreView() {
        stackView.insertSubview(view3, at: 3)
        stackView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Current Layout

```
 view.addSubview(stackView)
 stackView.addArrangedSubview(view1)       
 stackView.addArrangedSubview(view2)       
 stackView.addArrangedSubview(view4)
 stackView.addArrangedSubview(view5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift provides the following `UIStackView` function to insert a view at a specified position:

```
func insertArrangedSubview(_ view: UIView, atIndex stackIndex: Int)
```

(see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/1616237-insertarrangedsubview) for more information)

Comment: then view3.removeFromSuperview(). the layout is updated too?

Comment: Yes, in stackview auto update subviews inside it. if you remove view or set hidden target view it automatically reload and update layout. [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
func insertArrangedSubview(_ view: UIView, at stackIndex: Int)
```

like that:

```
stackView.insertArrangedSubview(view3, at: 3)
```

Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/1616237-insertarrangedsubview)